# Translating this C struct to C#

Tags: c#, c, struct

I'm translating a C game: https://github.com/minirop/Super-Mario-Remake to C# for fun and to improve my C# programming. I'm not that experienced in programming in C and came across a struct that i don't know how to implement in C#.

```
    typedef struct _state_t {
    void (*init)(struct _state_t * s);
    void (*update)(struct _state_t * s, Uint32 elapsedTime);
    void (*handleEvent)(struct _state_t * s);
    void (*draw)(struct _state_t * s, SDL_Surface * surface);
    void (*clean)(struct _state_t * s);
    void * data;
} state_t;
```

What i tried so far is:

```
public class state_t
{
    public void init(state_t S)
    {
        state_t s;

        s = S;
    }

    public void update(state_t S, UInt32 ElapsedTime)
    {
        state_t s;
        UInt32 elapsedTime;

        s = S;
        elapsedTime = ElapsedTime;
    }

    public void handleEvent(state_t S)
    {
        state_t s;
        s = S;
    }

    public void draw(state_t S, SDL.SDL_Surface Surface)
    {
        state_t s;
        SDL.SDL_Surface surface;

        s = S;
        surface = Surface;
    }
    public void clean(state_t S)
    {
        state_t s;

        s = S;
    }

    public void data()
    {

    }
}
```

But i don't think this is right. I got an error:

```
        state_t MS_get()
        {
           state_t state = new state_t();
           state.init = MS_init; // Error 2 Cannot assign to 'init' because it is a 'method group'

        }  ...
```

Comment: My C is rusted, but it looks like a function pointer. So `init` should translate to something like `public Action<_state_t> init;`. That said, if you try a 1:1 conversion you'll quickly run into C# limitations. It's better to try to understand the code then rewrite it with an OOP approach.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will try that. Yeah it's also my intention to rewrite this to an OOP aproach. I'm not an experienced programmer in general, so i trial and error alot.

Comment: It is the rough equivalent of an interface.  The members are all data, not code.  Function pointers.  You write the equivalent struct with delegate members.   You need to declare the delegate types first, they need the [UnmanagedFunctionPointer] attribute to change the CallingConvention to Cdecl.  If you are supposed to initialize the struct instead of using it then initialize the member delegate objects to target a method in your code.  Be sure to store it in a *static* variable so the garbage collector doesn't get rid of it.  Lots of ways to lose, easier to do in C++/CLI.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `init` as a method, therefore you need to call it; not assign it. Something like this should work:

`state.init(MS_init);`

However, I see inside that method you are just saving the state in a variable that is declared inside the `init()` method, this will achieve nothing.

Comment: Yeah i was not done with programming the methods. It was a direct translation from the C struct to C# of what i thought it was right. That's the problem for not understanding this C struct.

Answer (score 0):

This C struct is made from a C++ or a C# object oriented class in the first place.The object oriented principles are forced onto this struct.

The equivalent C# struct will be

```
public class state_t
{
    Unit32 m_elapsedTime;
    SDL_Surface * m_surface;
    void *m_data;

    public void init()
    {
       // Initialise all variables of class
    }

    public void update(UInt32 ElapsedTime)
    {
        m_elapsedTime = ElapsedTime;
    }

    public void handleEvent()
    {
       // Code for Handle Event
    }

    public void draw(SDL_Surface Surface)
    {
       // Code for Draw
       m_surface = Surface;  // maybe, need to check datatype.
    }
    public void clean()
    {
       // Code for Cleaning
    }

    public void data()
    {
       // Code for filling *data variable
    }
}
```

You may need to add a few more private variables, especially with regards to memory allocation sizes of `m_data` and `m_surface`, but that will depend on further examination of the original code.

Comment: These: SDL_Surface * m_surface; void *m_data;

Comment: From a reading of the code given in the link, these variables are dynamically allocated. So, you will need pointers to store them.